# Android Music Player: Album name is getting repeated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

This code is getting the albums of all the songs, but it is if there are 5 songs in a particular album, the album name is appearing 5 times, simultaneously. How to avoid this?

```
public class AlbumListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView lv;

public AlbumListFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_album, container, false);
    final ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    lv=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvalbum);
    String[] proj={MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM};
    final Cursor c=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null) {
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                int index=c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                arr.add(c.getString(index));
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    } c.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the MediaStore.Audio.**Albums** class like so:

```
 String[] proj={MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM};
 final Cursor c=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
```

You just have to replace MediaStore.Audio.Media with MediaStore.Audio.Albums and your code should work.

Don't forget to accept it as the answer to your question to get more reputation.

Comment: So easy, yet hard to find. For reference see [MediaStore.Audio.Albums](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Albums.html)